# Assign and dereference void * to an array pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

I have a pointer to array of fixed size integer elements. After populating that array, I assigned it to void *pBuff. Later on, I need to access array elements through void pointer which I failed in doing so.

Here is the code using C:

```
void * pBuff = NULL;

int
set_data(void *pBuff)
{
    int ptr = 10, i;
    int phy_bn[8] = {0};
    int (*pPB)[8];

    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        phy_bn[i] = ptr;
    }

    pPB = &phy_bn;
    pBuff = pPB;

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int i;

    set_data(&pBuff);

    for(i =0 ; i <8; i++){
         printf("\ndata : %d\n", *(int *)pBuff[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prompts an error  *cast of 'void' term to non-'void'*  against *(int *)pBuff[i].

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

-Sam

Comment: Note that your `pBuff` is pointing at memory on the stack which is no longer valid.

Comment: It's bad enough to have globals, but it's a really really really bad idea to have globals and parameters with the same names. Also, you need to get a basic grasp on the notion of types. `pBuff` has type `void*` but `&pBuff` has type `void**`, which should not be passed to a function that takes an argument of type `void*`.

Comment: @JesseGood: actually, it is not (in an even worse way). The local variable `pBuff` is set but assigning to a local variable has no effect on anything outside the function. The global variable `pBuff` is never actually modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you need to use:

```
((int*)pBuff)[i]
```

What you have in your code is **Undefined Behavior**.

```
pBuff = pPB;
```

`pBuff` points to a array which is local to the function and its lifetime does not exist beyond the function scope. So you have a pointer pointing to something that does not need to exist but may seemingly exist sometimes.

Comment: actually, (confusinglly) the `pBuff = pPB;` line is fine, since that `pBuff` is a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably dereference with `*` or `[]`, *not* both at the same time :-)

If your intent is to get the integer at that `i` position of a void pointer which points to `int`s, use:

```
((int*)pBuff)[i]
```

The `((int*)pBuff)` turns `pBuff` into a pointer to an integer and the `[i]` following that grabs the `i`'th integer at that location.

So your loop would be:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 8; i++)
     printf ("\ndata : %d\n", ((int*)pBuff)[i]);
```

---

Another thing you should probably watch out for is returning pointer to stack-based variables. Those variables *disappear* when the function exits at which point dereferencing pointers to them is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`pBuff[i]` is illegal, since `pBuff` is a `void*`. It's a matter of operator precedence:

```
((int *)pBuff)[i]
```

You don't need to dereference `pBuff` again with the first `*` because `[i]` already does that.

Comment: there are other issues in his program that you are not addressing..specially the `local scope` problem

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It ah, missed that. Pointed out in the other answers now.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
void * pBuff = NULL;

int
set_data(void *pBuff)
{
    int ptr = 10, i;
    int *phy_bn = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*8);
    //this is needed so that it is valid for pBuff to point phy_bn even if it is getting out of scope

    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        phy_bn[i] = ptr;
    }

    pBuff = phy_bn;

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int i;

    set_data(&pBuff);

    for(i =0 ; i <8; i++){
         printf("\ndata : %d\n", ((int*)pBuff)[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No it shouldn't. `set_data` takes an argument of type `void*`, but `&pBuff` is of type `void**`. And setting `pBuff` at the end of `set_data` sets the parameter, which is never used, not the global. There are other problems with this code as well.

Comment: It says unhandled exception at ((int*)pBuff)[i] as an access voilation with 0xC0000005.

Comment: @JimBalter : what are those? It would be great if you correct them.

Comment: @Sam Those are that `set_data` pointlessly returns a value, `malloc` should not be cast, the argument to `set_data` should be `void** pBuff`, the final statement should be `*pBuff = phy_bn`, `phy_bn` can't be on the stack ... maybe there are more as well. A basic question: *why* use `void*` when `int*` is intended?